# Is prefixing a media query with *, such as *-device-width, a valid query for the @media rule?

Tags: css, media-queries, device-width

Some of our company's sites use @media rules where the query uses device-width, e.g.

```
@media (max-device-width:800px) {} //various rules
```

I was searching through our company sites' CSS to find any outdated rules when I came across [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en) link. The authors assert asterisk-prefixing such as with `*-device-width` is possible for media queries, and since it's a Google link this assertion must be correct :p

I cannot test this with my current setup. I tried applying this rule on W3Schools and their setup but it did not seem to work (though valid queries did work). The MDN page for @media [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) does not make any mention of the validity of this query. Neither do WHATWG docs such as [this](https://compat.spec.whatwg.org/#css-media-queries) one nor W3C docs such as [this](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-3/#media0) one.

Is asterisk-prefixing such as `*-device-width` valid for a media query, such that the rule applies to both `max-device-width` AND `min-device-width`?

Comment: Never thought I'd say this, but WHATWG is not W3C, and just like W3C hates being mistaken for W3Schools, WHATWG hates just as much to be confused with W3C. Also, the WHATWG spec you link to describes non-standard features - if you're trying to find out if device-width is part of the standard, why are you looking there?

Comment: Just came across it when googling "device-width" for a different issue I had with our company CSS - use of @-ms-viewport {width: device-width;}

Comment: Also I chose the "Living Standard" from the MDN page - could of chosen this one: https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-3/#media0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is asterisk-prefixing such as `*-device-width` valid for a media query, such that the rule applies to both `max-device-width` AND `min-device-width`?

No, it's not. The way to refer to a media feature by itself is to simply omit any prefixes. So in this case it's `device-width`. See [section 4 of Media Queries 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1) and [section 2.4 of Media Queries 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-4/#mq-features).

I have no idea why the authors of that Google document refer to `*-device-width` when they could have simply said `device-width` — if I were to hazard a guess it's probably because `device-width` is used [elsewhere](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/set-the-viewport?hl=en) — but in any case, the asterisk is not a valid prefix.